# CSS/js cascading Verticle Menu accordion: trying to make my active page show as active

Tags: javascript, css, menu

given up tearing my hair out, can anyone help?
I'm trying to get the active page to apply a separate style, in the example same as when you click on test1 ie have the dark background hen on the homepage or about us.

http://www.tait-design.com/devsites/test-nav/index.asp

the main pages don't go anywhere ie test1 but the page test1-1 and test2-1 do as examples

I think the issue will lie in the js
http://www.tait-design.com/devsites/test-nav/js/accordion.js
and maybe the css (can't put the full url in)
/css/black.css
I've made a couple of the classes different colors on the text to help identify

I've picked up someone else's work I suspect it's a template site, which has been altered, the left nav wasn't done as an include so each page had a seperate markup to make the active page ...look active. I've changed this to asp just for the includes to work off my site, it will be php though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done purely in CSS, no Javascript is required.

- First, give unique classes to each of the `body` tags on your pages.
  For instance, on the home page it would be something like `<body
  class="home">`.
- Then give the anchor tag of the matching link the same class (ie,  - see that I've added a
  second class to the link).
- Now you can specifically style that link in CSS when it's the active
  page:

  body.home #menu-1 a.home {
   // whatever styling you like
  }